# TF/keras subclass works perfectly in Eager Execution, and throws a massive untraceable error without it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I learned to write custom layers from `keras.io`. Here it is:

```py
class modrelu(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(modrelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print(input_shape)
        self.b = self.add_weight(name='brad', shape=(input_shape[0][1],), initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(modrelu, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, list)
        ip_r, ip_i = x
        comp= tf.complex(ip_r, ip_i) 
        ABS= tf.math.abs(comp)
        ANG= tf.math.angle(comp)

        ABS= tf.nn.relu( self.b + ABS) 

        op_i=  ABS * tf.sin(ANG) #K.dot ??
        op_r= ABS * tf.cos(ANG)
        return [op_r, op_i]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        shape_a, shape_b = input_shape
        return [shape_a, shape_b]


act= modrelu()
a=tf.constant(np.array([[1,2], [4,4]]), dtype='float32')
b=tf.constant(np.array([[3,4], [5, -1]]), dtype='float32')
act([a,b])
```

When run in Eager execution, I get nice outputs. Without that mode, I get very weird error that I cannot even trace to where it started, it is in a different world. Here it is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py
>   in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
>       526     try:
>   --> 527       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
>       528     except TypeError:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py
>   in (.0)
>       526     try:
>   --> 527       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
>       528     except TypeError:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py
>   in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
>        60     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
>   ---> 61                     (bytes_or_text,))
>        62
>
> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got Dimension(2)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 a=tf.constant(np.array([[1,2], [4,4]]), dtype='float32')
>         3 b=tf.constant(np.array([[3,4], [5, -1]]), dtype='float32')
>   ----> 4 act([a,b])
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       744           # the user has manually overwritten the build method do we need to
>       745           # build it.
>   --> 746           self.build(input_shapes)
>       747         # We must set self.built since user defined build functions are not
>       748         # constrained to set self.built.
>
> in build(self, input_shape)
>         7         print(input_shape)
>         8         self.b = self.add_weight(name='brad', shape=(input_shape[0][1],), initializer='uniform',
>   ----> 9                                       trainable=True)
>        10 #        self.b= K.variable(value=np.random.rand(input_shape[0][1])-0.5,
>   dtype='float32') #
>        11         super(modrelu, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer,
>   trainable, constraint, partitioner, use_resource, synchronization,
>   aggregation, **kwargs)
>       607         collections=collections,
>       608         synchronization=synchronization,
>   --> 609         aggregation=aggregation)
>       610     backend.track_variable(variable)
>       611
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpointable\base.py
>   in _add_variable_with_custom_getter(self, name, shape, dtype,
>   initializer, getter, overwrite, **kwargs_for_getter)
>       637     new_variable = getter(
>       638         name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=initializer,
>   --> 639         **kwargs_for_getter)
>       640 
>       641     # If we set an initializer and the variable processed it, tracking will not
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in make_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, partition_info,
>   trainable, caching_device, validate_shape, constraint, use_resource,
>   collections, synchronization, aggregation, partitioner)    1975
>   collections=collections,    1976
>   synchronization=synchronization,
>   -> 1977       aggregation=aggregation)    1978   return v    1979
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py
>   in **call**(cls, *args, **kwargs)
>       181   def **call**(cls, *args, **kwargs):
>       182     if cls is VariableV1:
>   --> 183       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
>       184     elif cls is Variable:
>       185       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py
>   in _variable_v1_call(cls, initial_value, trainable, collections,
>   validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype,
>   expected_shape, import_scope, constraint, use_resource,
>   synchronization, aggregation)
>       144         use_resource=use_resource,
>       145         synchronization=synchronization,
>   --> 146         aggregation=aggregation)
>       147 
>       148   def _variable_v2_call(cls,
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py
>   in (**kwargs)
>       123                         aggregation=VariableAggregation.NONE):
>       124     """Call on Variable class. Useful to force the signature."""
>   --> 125     previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
>       126     for getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint:
>   disable=protected-access
>       127       previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py
>   in default_variable_creator(next_creator, **kwargs)    2435
>   caching_device=caching_device, name=name, dtype=dtype,    2436
>   constraint=constraint, variable_def=variable_def,
>   -> 2437         import_scope=import_scope)    2438   else:    2439     return variables.RefVariable(
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py
>   in **call**(cls, *args, **kwargs)
>       185       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
>       186     else:
>   --> 187       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).**call**(*args, **kwargs)
>       188 
>       189
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py
>   in **init**(self, initial_value, trainable, collections,
>   validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def,
>   import_scope, constraint)
>       295           name=name,
>       296           dtype=dtype,
>   --> 297           constraint=constraint)
>       298 
>       299   # pylint: disable=unused-argument
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py
>   in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections,
>   validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint)
>       407           with ops.name_scope("Initializer"), ops.device(None):
>       408             initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(
>   --> 409                 initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
>       410                 name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
>       411           self._handle = eager_safe_variable_handle(
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py
>   in ()    1957         initializer = initializer(dtype=dtype)
>   1958       init_val = lambda: initializer(  # pylint:
>   disable=g-long-lambda
>   -> 1959           shape, dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)    1960       variable_dtype = dtype.base_dtype    1961   if use_resource
>   is None:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py
>   in **call**(self, shape, dtype, partition_info)
>       253       dtype = self.dtype
>       254     return random_ops.random_uniform(
>   --> 255         shape, self.minval, self.maxval, dtype, seed=self.seed)
>       256 
>       257   def get_config(self):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py
>   in random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed, name)
>       233     maxval = 1
>       234   with ops.name_scope(name, "random_uniform", [shape, minval, maxval]) as name:
>   --> 235     shape = _ShapeTensor(shape)
>       236     minval = ops.convert_to_tensor(minval, dtype=dtype, name="min")
>       237     maxval = ops.convert_to_tensor(maxval, dtype=dtype, name="max")
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py
>   in _ShapeTensor(shape)
>        42   else:
>        43     dtype = None
>   ---> 44   return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")
>        45 
>        46
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)    1048
>   name=name,    1049       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
>   -> 1050       as_ref=False)    1051     1052
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py
>   in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref,
>   preferred_dtype, ctx)    1144     1145     if ret is None:
>   -> 1146       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)    1147     1148     if ret is NotImplemented:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py
>   in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
>       227                                          as_ref=False):
>       228   _ = as_ref
>   --> 229   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>       230 
>       231
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py
>   in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
>       206   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
>       207       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
>   --> 208           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>       209   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
>       210   const_tensor = g.create_op(
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py
>   in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
>       529       raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
>       530                       "Contents: %s. Consider casting elements to a "
>   --> 531                       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
>       532     tensor_proto.string_val.extend(str_values)
>       533     return tensor_proto
>
> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor.
>   Contents: (Dimension(2),). Consider casting elements to a supported
>   type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting shape as `TensorShape` instance. You could use `as_list()` attribute to convert it to a Python list if the execution is not eager:

```py
if tf.executing_eagerly():
    shape = (input_shape[0][1], )
else:
    shape = (input_shape[0].as_list()[1], )
```

In your code it will be like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import numpy as np

class modrelu(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(modrelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        if tf.executing_eagerly():
            shape = (input_shape[0][1])
        else:
            shape = (input_shape[0].as_list()[1], )
        self.b = self.add_weight(name='brad',
                                 shape=shape,
                                 initializer='uniform',
                                 trainable=True)
        super(modrelu, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, list)
        ip_r, ip_i = x
        comp = tf.complex(ip_r, ip_i) 
        ABS = tf.math.abs(comp)
        ANG = tf.math.angle(comp)
        ABS = tf.nn.relu( self.b + ABS) 
        op_i =  ABS * tf.sin(ANG) #K.dot ??
        op_r = ABS * tf.cos(ANG)
        return [op_r, op_i]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        shape_a, shape_b = input_shape
        return [shape_a, shape_b]

act = modrelu()
a = tf.constant(np.array([[1,2], [4,4]]), dtype='float32')
b = tf.constant(np.array([[3,4], [5, -1]]), dtype='float32')
act([a,b])
# [<tf.Tensor 'modrelu_6/mul_1:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32>,
#  <tf.Tensor 'modrelu_6/mul:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: Okay, that was genius. But, why doesn't keras.io website show that?? I literally copied his example! Here, the second example here:
https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: Your example is a bit different since you're overriding `compute_output_shape()` method. The [default implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py) takes care of both eager and graph mode cases while computing the shape in `compute_output_shape()`.

Comment: Aaaah, you mean I modified that method .... yes, I did. I got it all. I reallly don't know how to thank you enough. You're literally a genius.